# "Not enough input arguments." when using fsolve with nested functions

Tags: matlab

I am trying to make my own function in matlab to solve for a system of two nonlinear equations, while using a nested function to share some some parameters, here is a sample code:

```
function y=solve(a,x0)
a;
y=fsolve(nle,x0);                       % this is line 3

    function f=nle(x)
        f(1)=x(1)-a*x(1)^2-x(1)*x(2);   % this is line 6
        f(2)=2*x(2)-x(2)+3*x(1)*x(2);
    end

end
```

Here `a` is the parameter I want to pass from command line to the function, and `x0` is the start point for the `fsolve`.

However, when I call the function in malab after specifying `a=4` and `x0=[1 1]'`, it gave me the following error:

```
Error using solve/nle (line 6)
Not enough input arguments.

Error in solve (line 3)
y=fsolve(nle,x0);
```

I'm quite a newbie for matlab, can anybody tell me where I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**
I tried substituting the `nle` with a function handle `@nle`, but seems something else went wrong:

```
Undefined function 'fsolve' for input arguments of type 'function_handle'.

Error in solve (line 3)
y=fsolve(@nle,x0);
```

Doesn't seem to make sense since I checked the documentation for `fsolve`, and it says it should indeed use a function handle there...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You miss the '@' in front of nle, i.e.

```
 y = fsolve(@nle,x0);
```

should work.

Comment: Thanks Andreas, I tried that but seems there something else wrong: It says "Undefined function 'fsolve' for input arguments of type 'function_handle'.

Error in solve (line 3)
y=fsolve(@nle,x0);"

Comment: Hmm, my Matlab help says that fsolve is in the Optimization toolbox. Could it be the case, that you dont have this toolbox installed? (Unfortunately the similar command fzero in the Matlab base package is just for scalar variables).

Comment: You are right... I tried a very simple function and it says fsolve is undefined... Seems the version in our lab is a classroom version and therefore is very primitive. Thanks very much!

Comment: By the way: The problem you state is analytically solveable (just in case your function is not just a test example). I think it has no solution, except for a specific value of A. So a numerical algorithm (like fsolve) will not converge and issue a warning anyway.

Comment: Yeah it is just a test example ;) Still it's helpful to know the warning thing. Thanks!